# String Matching: Matching words with or without spaces

Tags: string, algorithm

I want to find a way by which I can map "b m w" to "bmw" and "ali baba" to "alibaba" in both the following examples.

1. "b m w shops" and "bmw"

I need to determine whether I can write "b m w" as "bmw"

I thought of this approach:

remove spaces from the original string. This gives "bmwshops". And now find the Largest common substring in "bmwshop" and "bmw".

Second example:

1. "ali baba and 40 thieves"  and "alibaba and 40 thieves"

The above approach does not work in this case.

Is there any standard algorithm that could be used?

Comment: Why not just remove spaces from both? Both come to `alibabaand40thieves`.

Comment: the largest common substring is the entire second string: "alibabaand40thieves". No way of determining ali baba to alibaba mapping from that information

Comment: Do two comparisons, one with the spaces from the first removed, and one with the spaces from the second removed.

Comment: Is the second string always in the same order as the first one? Eg you will never have to deal with "word 1 word2" "word2 word1"

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to determine whether I can write "b m w" as "bmw""? How is the word that may be written differently defined and what is the output of your program? Otherwise I don't see why you cant compare  alibabaand40thieves to  alibabaand40thieves and say: "yes, it fits"

Comment: Maybe state some assumptions such as: do you already have a dictionary that you can check against to see if it is a word?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking this question: "How do I determine if string A can be made equal to string B by removing (some) spaces?".

What you can do is iterate over both strings, advancing within both whenever they have the same character, otherwise advancing along the first when it has a space, and returning false otherwise. Like this:

```
static bool IsEqualToAfterRemovingSpacesFromOne(this string a, string b) {
    return a.IsEqualToAfterRemovingSpacesFromFirst(b)
        || b.IsEqualToAfterRemovingSpacesFromFirst(a);
}
static bool IsEqualToAfterRemovingSpacesFromFirst(this string a, string b) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i < a.Length && j < b.Length) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            i += 1
            j += 1
        } else if (a[i] == ' ') {
            i += 1;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return i == a.Length && j == b.Length;
}
```

The above is just an ever-so-slightly modified string comparison. If you want to extend this to 'largest common substring', then take a largest common substring algorithm and do the same sort of thing: whenever you would have failed due to a space in the first string, just skip past it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [Suffix Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array
or Here from Jon Bentley - [Programming Pearl](http://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&lpg=PA166&ots=DgyRwNFPau&dq=programming%20pearls%20suffix%20array&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=programming%20pearls%20suffix%20array&f=false)

**Note** : you have to write code to handle spaces.